# Sencha Cmd won't build on another workstation

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-cmd

So I am trying to set up another ExtJS (4.2.1) dev workstation I've got Ruby 1.9.3, Sencha Cmd 4.0.4.84 installed and latest Java VM too.

The build won't work on this one though, I'm getting:

```
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
Errno::ENOENT on line ["38"] of C: No such file or directory - C:/devtfs/CustomerPortal/CustomerPortal.UI/Content/Customer_Portal_UI/build/temp/production/Customer_Portal_UI/slicer-temp/.sass-cache/82daaa66b7a4761963814fd25131bf0f81370ec9/Customer_Portal_UI-example.scssc
```

`82daaa66b7a4761963814fd25131bf0f81370ec9` folder does exist, but it's empty.

I've tried

```
sencha ant clean
sencha app refresh
sencha app build --clean
```

No go. Ever seen this issue ?

Thanks!

EDIT: Hmm, even after this error, the application seems to be running fine on the Sencha web server, but the index.html file is the last thing that's not created in build/production.

Comment: Could it be a permission issue? If the folder exists, but no files, I wonder if Cmd isn't allowed to create files (or something) on the new workstation.

Comment: @arthurakay Yes, I thought of that too. The ExtJS application is under source countrol (TFS 2010) but I made sure everything was checked out. I can create files in said directory manually. This is a Windows 2008 Server box so maybe there's something in UAC I need to check.

Comment: do you have the /build/ folder under source control? More specifically, the .sass-cache folder? It should not be

Comment: @arthurakay No, I learned the hard way that it should not as TFS then whine about thousands of files missing when you clean/refresh your solution which prevents you from checking in changes :\ I'll get back with the solution if I find it.